# Running external script using truffle to interact with my contract

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Is it common to run external scripts with truffle? I keep seeing posts online with long js scripts to interact with contracts, but had no clue how people were running them outside of the console, which only accepts one-liners.

Anyway, I used the documentation to find out that my external script can be executed like this

```
truffle exec ./scripts/script.js
```

However, I'm getting an error that `HodlEthereum is not defined` when I try to run it.
[The documentation states](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/scripts) that I must use the `module.exports` encapsulation of my script. I've pasted what I have below:

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
    console.log(HodlEthereum.at("0x82d50ad3c1091866e258fd0f1a7cc9674609d254"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that HodlEthereum is a contract that is part of your truffle project, try adding this to the top of your script:

```
const HodlEthereum = artifacts.require('HodlEthereum');
```